# unhandled win32 exception in WolframKernel.exe in DSolve of non-linear ODE in one variable

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, crash

**Bug persisting through 10.4. (windows 7, 64 bit)**

---

Installed 10.3.1 and started to run some old ode's. in V 9, this ode used to return unsolved, which is ok, but in 10.3.1 now the kernel crashes. This is on windows 7, 64 bits.  I wonder if this also happens on other systems. I will also send email to support@wolfram.com

```
$Version
Clear[y, x];
DSolve[y'[x] - Cos[2 x] - Sin[2 x] y[x] - y[x]^2 == 0, y[x], x]
```

**Version 9**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Version 10.3.1**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**added**:

FYI, this is assigned CASE: 3498408 at WRI

Comment: I got no crash with version 10.3.1 on Win7 x64: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/04Wh2.png).

Comment: @Nasser `The kernel Local has quit (exited) during the course of an evaluation.` on Windows 10x64, Mathematica 10.3.1

Comment: Reproduced on Mac, 10.3.1.