# new kernel crashes using DSolve in 10.3.1

Tags: differential-equations, crash

Update:  I added small movie showing the crash, since others who tried it so far could not reproduce it on their system.

[image]

---

**Original question**

I am finding new problems with `DSolve` in 10.3.1. Here is another crash. could someone see if they can duplicate this? This happens on windows 7, 64 bit. It is reproducible. I was not sure if I should add this to my earlier finding [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102733/unhandled-win32-exception-in-wolframkernel-exe-in-dsolve-of-non-linear-ode-in-on) or make new question about it since it is different problem and do not know if they are related internally or not. Will also send email to support@wolfram.com to investigate. ps. It takes 3 minutes to get the crash. PC running intel fast CPU with 16 GB ram.

**First one**

```
$Version
Clear[x, y];
eq = x^3 + y[x] y'[x] + x y'[x]^2;
DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image]

With version 9, it does not crash, but also it is still running after 20 minutes. So it looks like it hanged. But no kernel crash ! (which is better, a hanged kernel or one that crashes? :)

**second one**

Here is a second crash on new problem I just found: (all with new fresh Kernel) This one took about 5 minutes.

```
$Version
Clear[x, y];
DateString[]
eq = D[y[x], x]^3 - 2*y[x]*D[y[x], x] + y[x]^2;
DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Third one**

This one is very similar in pattern to the above, small variation. Thought to put it here for reference.

```
$Version
Clear[x, y];
DateString[]
eq = D[y[x], x]^3 - y[x]*D[y[x], x]^2 + y[x]^2;
DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How long did it take to see the kernel crash on V 10.3.1?

Comment: No crash on linux with both 10.3.0 and 10.3.1 .

Comment: @b.gatessucks thanks for checking. It must be a windows only issue then. I am using windows 7, service pack 1, 64 bit.

Comment: @Nasser: For me, the first example was running for hours, with no signs of anything. Certainly that is very unusual, so the thing was hung, but just in a different way.

Comment: I notice that *Mathematica* is still orange...

Comment: I have tried the "Third one" example. With version 10.3.1 on Windows 7 x64 it runs more than 2 hours without crashing.

Comment: Thanks for trying. It crashes all the time on my Mathematica. May be there is something different in my system. Using service pack 1, windows 7. On fresh kernel. I can reproduce this all the time. I wish there is a dump file or some other log that the kernel writes when it crashes. This is very annoying that there is no log or dump file generated to look at.

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1509), Mma 10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015), the first example returns with an implicit solution in a few seconds.  The other two ran for several minutes, and then I killed them.

Comment: Actually, looking closely at the solution to the first, http://i.stack.imgur.com/ggBj3.png, one can see an invalid integral, ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pL4jZ.png)

Comment: I have tried also the "First one" example with the same result: it is running already more than 3.5 hours without crashing (system configuration is the same as above, all updates for Windows 7 are installed).